# PhP Error: FUNCTION

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
<?php
function me1($str) {
$hash = 'http://me1.wink.ws/me1/request.php?a=' . $str;
return $hash
}
$hi = me1('Hi');
?>
```

Where is my error?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/u727762781/public_html/client/me1.php on line 5

Fixed Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
function me1($str) {
$hash = file_get_contents('http://me1.wink.ws/me1/request.php?a=' . $str);
return $hash;
}
$hi = me1('Hi');
echo $hi;
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: i would down-vote my own post if i could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the semi-colon at the end of the return statement.